# How to upload a full project to Git repository?

Tags: git

There is the following problem: I'm new in Git, and I've made only a one project. I start a new project in Git using the following way:
1) create a new folder
2) initialize a git in this folder
3) create a new project using Eclipse
4) work with this project

But know I've got a big project (not a new one), and I want to upload it into Git repository. Please, tell me, how can I do it? If I just initialize a git in folder with my project I've got no new files right?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on their site? Search on Youtube?

Comment: Is the repository remote? Where is the repository located?

Comment: repository is remote - BitBucket

Answer (score 0):

You need to init git in this folder right. But you will gain new folders and files like .git or .gitignore. If you upload the stuff the files wont appear and everything looks the same!

Init process:

```
cd my_project
git init
git add *
git commit -m "My initial commit message"
git remote add origin git@example.com:my_project.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: What? The `.git` directory contains the repository data and `.gitignore` contains a list of files and directories the developer intentionally wants to exclude. What are you trying to say?

Comment: He ask if he will gain new files and i said yes u gain new files on git init. Thanks for downvote btw. sometimes i realy wonder why should i help.

Comment: `git init` does not create a `.gitignore`, and you don't necessarily want to add every file in the directory like your answer suggests.

Comment: Ok my fail no .gitignore gets created you are right huraaaay. But what a stupid conversation is this here. Git init creates an empty git repository - basically a .git directory with subdirectories for objects, refs/heads, refs/tags, and template files. An initial HEAD file that references the HEAD of the master branch is also created. So my answer if files gets created is yes. And if a git beginner ask how to upload a project then i dont start explaining how a gitignore is working and how to not upload every file.

Answer (score 0):

You should look around for some Git tutorials (I've written one you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/3998315), and I'm sure Bitbucket even has some decent ones), but the basics of what you would do is:

- Clone the repository, which will both create your directory and initialize Git to point to the remote repository with something like `git clone <Bitbucket repository path> <directory name>`
- [Create a `.gitignore` to ignore files you don't want](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) to push to the repository (such as personal configuration files and files generated when building your code, like object files and your built executable).
- Add the rest of the files using [git add](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).
- Commit these files using [git commit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)
- Push your commit(s) using [git push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).